# ICal Events Not Showing Up In Device Calendar

Tags: sync, calendar, sony-xperia

I have a Sony Xperia Z with Android 5.1.1, and I'm trying to get events from calendars I subscribed to on Google Calendar's web interface to show up on my stock calendar app. Specifically, some of the calendars I subscribed to don't show up in the app. I tried checking if they were disabled but they aren't even in the calendar list on the sidebar.

Using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.drlue.icalimportexport) I was able to find that the calendar subscriptions I wanted actually exist on my device but are listed with "0 events," even though their events show up on Google Calendar's web interface.

I have tried rebooting my device, checking that all calendars are enabled both in the stock calendar app and in settings, and manually syncing from settings.

How can I get the calendar events to sync and show up?

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to fix this.

If anyone else has this problem:

- Go to Settings > Apps > All and clear data and cache for Calendar and Calendar Storage
- Go to Settings > Accounts > Google, choose the menu and re-sync all
- Wait for sync
- Open the Calendar app and set it up again

Answer (score 0):

It's either a sync issue like the previous answer OR you might have multiple Google accounts on your phone and Google Calendar is only showing calendar events for your default Google Account.

In your app settings make sure that the tag group for ICal is set set to sync.

[image]